# If statement only showing else portion

Tags: python, if-statement, arguments, repeat

I'm writing code for a rock, paper, scissors game but the if statement in the function identify_winner is not running. The only thing that prints out is the else statement and it prints out for all outcomes, not just when it's a tie. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the variables but I don't know what it is.

```
import random

ROCK = 1
PAPER = 2
SCISSORS = 3
def main():
    user_choose(None)
    comp_choose(None)
    identify_winner()

def user_choose(weapon):
    weapon = int(input('Choose Your Weapon' + '\n (Rock = 1, Paper = 2' +\
                       ' Scissors = 3): '))
    if weapon == 1:
        print('You have chosen Rock')
    elif weapon == 2:
        print('You have chosen Paper')
    elif weapon == 3:
        print('You have chosen Scissors')

def comp_choose(choice):
    if random.randint(1,3) == 1:
        choice = 'Rock'
    elif random.randint(1,3) == 2:
        choice = 'Paper'
    else:
        choice = 'Scissors'
    print('Your enemy has chosen',choice)

def identify_winner():
    user = 0
    comp = 0
    while user == comp:
        user_choose(user)
        comp_choose(comp)
        if (user == 1 and comp == 3) or (user ==2 and comp == 1) or (user == 3 and comp 
        == 2):
            print('Congratulations! You have defeated the foe!')
        elif (comp ==1 and user == 3) or (comp == 2 and user == 1) or (comp == 3 and 
        user == 2):
            print('Alas, you have been defeated! Better luck next time!')
        else:
            print('Oh no, a tie! choose again!')

    

main()
```

Comment: The problem is with the scope of the comp and user variables. identify_winner creates local comp and user variables but these are NOT changed by the _choose functions. You should return a value from each _choose function and pick these up in identify_winner.

Answer (score 0):

I made some little changes in your code. Commented the parts for explanation:

```py
import random

# you never use those, so they are not needed here:
# ROCK = 1
# PAPER = 2
# SCISSORS = 3

def user_choose(): # no input argument needed since you define weapon in the next line anyway
    weapon = int(input('Choose Your Weapon' + '\n (Rock = 1, Paper = 2' +\
                       ' Scissors = 3): '))
    
    # this part is asking for a number as long as user don't choose a valid number between 1 and 3.
    # You could do even more here, check for number or letter, check if number is 0 or negative
    while weapon>3: 
        weapon = int(input('No valid number. Please choose again: ' + '\n (Rock = 1, Paper = 2' +\
                       ' Scissors = 3): '))
        
    if weapon == 1:
        print('You have chosen Rock')
    elif weapon == 2:
        print('You have chosen Paper')
    elif weapon == 3:
        print('You have chosen Scissors')
    return weapon # you need to return the variable weapon, otherwise it is only in the local scope and your main function doesn't have access to it

def comp_choose(): # same as in the other function, no input argument needed
    choice = random.randint(1,3) # in your code random.randint(1,3) executes twice and can have two different results. You want it once and then check on it
    if choice == 1:
        chose = 'Rock' # in the main() func you compare the numbers, but in your code user has numbers between 1 and 3 and comp has values with rock, paper, scissors.
    elif choice == 2:
        chose = 'Paper'
    else:
        choice = 3
        chose = 'Scissors'
    print('Your enemy has chosen',chose)
    return choice # same as in the other function with 'weapon'

def main(): # identy_winner() isn't needed. two functions for user and comp with the main to select winner is enough
    run = True
    while run: # doing it like this you can make the user choose if he wants to continue or not (later at the 'continue_playing' part)
        user = user_choose() # get access to the return value of the function
        comp = comp_choose() # get access to the return value of the function
        if (user == 1 and comp == 3) or (user ==2 and comp == 1) or (user == 3 and comp 
        == 2):
            print('Congratulations! You have defeated the foe!')
        elif (comp ==1 and user == 3) or (comp == 2 and user == 1) or (comp == 3 and 
        user == 2):
            print('Alas, you have been defeated! Better luck next time!')
        else:
            print('Oh no, a tie! choose again!')
        
        continue_playing = input('You want to play again? [y/n]: ')
        if continue_playing == 'n':
            run = False

main()
```

The code will crash if the user chooses a letter instead of numbers, and working poorly if he chooses numbers 0 or less. You may want to check for that.... I leave that up to you.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost it is not a good practice to call main function directly as it was a script. If you plan to create not script program you should scope main function inside.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Secondly, you don't need to call user_choose and comp_choose inside identify winner, you can just return those values in your main program and give them as arguments to your identify winner function. Also you should not generate two times a random number in your comp_choose() because in the second elif you could generate the previous number so comp choice most likely be Scissors. I give you one possible solution to your problem:

```
import random

ROCK = 1
PAPER = 2
SCISSORS = 3

def main():
    identify_winner(user_choose(), comp_choose())

def user_choose():
    weapon = int(input('Choose Your Weapon' + '\n (Rock = 1, Paper = 2' +\
                       ' Scissors = 3): '))
    if weapon == 1:
        print('You have chosen Rock')
    elif weapon == 2:
        print('You have chosen Paper')
    elif weapon == 3:
        print('You have chosen Scissors')
    
    return weapon

def comp_choose():
    comp_weapon = random.randint(1,3)
    if comp_weapon == 1:
        choice = 'Rock'
    elif comp_weapon == 2:
        choice = 'Paper'
    else:
        choice = 'Scissors'
    print('Your enemy has chosen',choice)
    return comp_weapon

def identify_winner(user, comp):
    
    if (user == 1 and comp == 3) or (user ==2 and comp == 1) or (user == 3 and comp 
    == 2):
        print('Congratulations! You have defeated the foe!')
    elif (comp ==1 and user == 3) or (comp == 2 and user == 1) or (comp == 3 and 
    user == 2):
        print('Alas, you have been defeated! Better luck next time!')
    else:
        print('Oh no, a tie! choose again!')


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```